# Auto close google app script dialog when processing is finished

Tags: javascript, user-interface, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform

I have a custom dialog that gets replaced by the below code for processing to complete. I don't want to add a link or a button to the below dialog however I want "google.script.host.close();" to close the below dialog when my code is finished processing. What am I missing?

```
// start processing and autoclose the dialog
  var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("autoclose_progress_dialog")
                                            .setWidth(260)
                                            .setHeight(50);
  ui.showModalDialog(output, 'It will take a few secs...');
```

The model dialog html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><base target="_top">
  </head>
  <h4>Processing your request...</h4>
  <body>
    <script>
          google.script.run.startDashboardProcessing();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want the dialog to auto-close when "startDashboardProcessing()" is finished processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about doing a `google.script.host.close()` in the success handler of `google.script.run.startDashboardProcessing()`

Something like this:

```
function onSuccess() {
  google.script.host.close()
}

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).startDashboardProcessing()
```

REF: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showmodaldialoguserinterface,-title

Comment: excellent, it works! I saw the link earlier and tried but I guess I missed something. Below is the HTML code that worked.

    <html>
     <head><base target="_top"></head>
     <h4>Processing your request...</h4>
     <body>
     <script>      
       function onSuccess() {
        google.script.host.close();
       }
       function onFailure() {
        google.script.run.dashboardProcessingFailed();
       }
       google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).withFailureHandler(onFailure).createDashboard();
      </script>
      </body>
    </html>